# Can I change the boost lib files' names?

Tags: c++, boost

I installed boost with cmd `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev`. I find my boost lib files under `/usr/lib` are these:

```
$ ls /usr/lib | grep boost
libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1
libboost_iostreams.so.1.46.1
libboost_python-py27.so.1.46.1
libboost_python-py32.so.1.46.1
libboost_regex.a
libboost_regex-mt.a
libboost_regex-mt.so
libboost_regex.so
libboost_regex.so.1.46.1
libboost_serialization.so.1.46.1
libboost_system.so.1.46.1
libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
libboost_wserialization.so.1.46.1
```

Now I want to link my program with boost.

G++: `g++ test.cc -lboost_regex -lboost-iostreams -g -o prog`

Result: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams`

Does the lib file name `libboost_iostreams.so.1.46.1` cause this problem? If so, can I rename it to `libboost_iostreams.so`?

And why I have `libboost_regex.so` and `libboost_regex.so.1.46.1`? Are they the same or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against renaming the library. Creating a soft link is preferable. I am not sure how `apt-get` deals with files that are deleted or renamed by a user instead of by `apt-get` itself.

`libboost_regex.so` is most likely a soft link to `libboost_regex.so.1.46.1`

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to create symbolic links named what you want pointing to the actual files.  For example, on the Mac OS X, if I run:

```
ls -l `which lynx` | more
```

then I see all of the links.  Some of which look like:

```
c++ -> clang++
cc -> clang
jar -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/jar
```

The link creation command is `ln`.  To make a symbolic link use the `-s` option like so:

```
ln -s /path_to_source_file /path_to_symbolic_link
```

Example for the boost iostream library path above:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.46.1 /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so
```

Be prepared to prepend `sudo` in front of the `ln` command.  Every time I have modified the `/usr/..` area, I have had to use `sudo` on my MacBook Pro.  I expect the same from Ubuntu.  To remove a symbolic link type:

```
rm /path_to_symbolic_link
```

Keep in mind that `sudo` may be necessary again.